# Isolated point of a set is a border point of complement

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that an isolated point of set $S$ is a boundary point of the complement of set $S$.

My attempt:

Let $x$ be an isolated point of $S$. i.e there exists a neighborhood $U$ for point $x$ which contains no other points of $S$. Then $U$ contains at least one point of $S^c$

So we see that every neighborhood of $x$ contains the point $x$∈$S$ and at least one point of $S^c$, therefore $x$ is a boundary point of $S^c$.

I'm not sure if this is proof enough. How do I show that **every** neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $S^c$?

Comment: In the discrete space $\{0,1\}$, $1$ is isolated for $\{1\}$ but the boundary of its complement $\{0\}$ is $\emptyset$. Saw the tag, *real analysis* now. Then intersect the arbitrary neighborhood with the neighborhood that came from isolated. That intersection is also open and open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ have infinitely many points. Some of them are not $x$ and therefore belong to the complement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an alternate proof

$\partial S^c = \overline{S^c}\cap \overline{S}$ and it is obvious that $x$ is in both $\overline{S^c}$ and $\overline{S}$.